# Exit sticky state in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, sticky

I have my `/home` as a sticky state (reasons about why I have set it up like this are out of the scope of this question) and I have a few links (`ui-sref`).

I realized that the only way other states will draw is by adding `ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"` to each `ui-sref`, but I'm not really sure I understand why this is happening or if that is the right way of "exiting" a sticky state.

Are there any better ways of exiting a sticky state? What does `reload` implies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. `ui-sref-opts="{exitSticky: 'the-name-of-my-sticky-state'}"`

Source: https://github.com/ui-router/sticky-states/issues/5